# Importing variables from another python script help needed

Tags: python, variables, python-import

I have tow python script running on the same computer at he same time. I need one script to import variables from the other script. I don't want to import functions, I want data, accurate to the second. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you already try threading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you take the data from the variable and put it into an external file then access the information that way.

Example:

a.py

```
import json
    
data = 1
with open(r"examples\data.json", "w") as json_file:
    info = {"Data" : data}
    json.dump(info, json_file)
```

b.py

```
import json

with open(r"examples\data.json", "r") as json_file:
    file = json.load(json_file)
    data = file["Data"]
```

data.json

```
{"Data": "1"}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I got this error when I ran your code:     
```
    Traceback  (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/lib-python/examples/sever.py", line 13, in <module>
    with open("data", "r") as json_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data'
```

Comment: Make sure data.json is in your current working directory. + I changed the code a little to specify that it's a JSON file and that it's in the examples folder. Make those changes and the code should work without any problems.